# Flutter make TableRow take the rest available space

Tags: flutter

I have a table with 3 rows, the `IntrinsicColumnWidth` method set the sizes of the column according to the intrinsic dimensions of all the cells in that column. that means that they will take the minimum possible width. that exactly what i want for the first and the second column.
My question is how can i make the third row takes the rest available space

```
Table(
   columnWidths: {
     0: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
     1: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
     2: IntrinsicColumnWidth(), // i want this one to take the rest available space
   },
   ...
),
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know it's late, but to anyone else looking for an answer to this question, you can try the code below.

```
Table(
   columnWidths: {
     0: FlexColumnWidth(1.0),
     1: FlexColumnWidth(1.0),
     2: IntrinsicColumnWidth(), // i want this one to take the rest available space
   },
   ...
),
```

Comment: Explaining why this code is supposed to work would make your answer a better teaching materials.